# Writing a JSON file a string

Tags: javascript, json

could someone give me some direction on how to write a piece of JSON text in JavaScript. eg

```
{
"Header.MainsiteURL": "http://www.ford.es",
"Header.backToMainsiteMobile": "ES-Main site"
}
```

Comment: what you tried so far ?

Comment: Can you show some effort on your part first?

Comment: I have tried to caption the quotation marks with      \"     _____    \"      which was not successful. I've also had a brief look at Java.lang.String to write it. But i'm very new to programming so I'm quite unsure

Comment: First things first, you should at least know, what programming language you're using. "_Java.lang.String_"? Are you using Java, not JavaScript?

Comment: That would be a good start. I'm using JavaScript

Comment: How is "_Java.lang.String_" then involved in the question?

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a single Json object using the following syntax.

```
var person = {
               Name: "NameOfPerson",
               Age: 23
             }
```

The following is a Json array for storing people's names and age.

```
var people = [
               {
                 Name: "NameOfPerson",
                 Age: 23
               },{
                 Name: "NameOfAnotherPerson",
                 Age: 12
               }
             ]
```

What you seem to be missing in your example are the properties of the object.